# Animated Model for Augmented Reality on Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I need to apply some animation on my model which is in .obj
Currently Im using Vuforia SDK and Artoolkit but seem both of them do not have any example showing that.

Anyone can enlightened me on this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know .obj does not support rigging and skeletal animation. You might be able to use a different .obj model for each of your animation frames. See this question as well: [Do Wavefront .obj files support animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757145/do-wavefront-obj-files-support-animation)

Answer (score 0):

.obj model don't support animation but you can use md2 models which have animation and they are very light. See my ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158889/1206201) to do this with Qcar.