# aframe Animations with OBJ

Tags: html, blender, aframe

I've successfully loaded my model in aframe. I have animations with a bone. I wanted to load that. Or maybe just key frames.

How can I export my blender bone animations for aframe? How do I call those animations?

Answer (score 6):

The [OBJ format does not support animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757145/do-wavefront-obj-files-support-animation), so you'll need to export to a different format if you want to play your animations.

<strike>My advice, if you're exporting from Blender to A-Frame, would be to use the Three.js JSON format. Three.js [provides a Blender exporter for this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender).</strike> Once you have a <strike>JSON</strike> glTF file, including your animations, you can load the file in A-Frame using the <strike>`json-model` (or perhaps `object-model`)</strike> `gltf-model` component, and `animation-mixer` from [A-Frame Extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras).

Example syntax:

```
<a-entity scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"
          animation-mixer
          gltf-model="src: url(./my-model.glb);">
</a-entity>
```

---

> *UPDATE(11/7/2019)*: With A-Frame 0.7.0+, the glTF 2.0 format (supported in Blender 2.8 and other tools) is the recommended choice with A-Frame. Usage is the same as above, using the `gltf-model` component.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You Cant Get Animated Model In Obj Format. In A-frame If You Want to Animate Its Better To User JSON Or Gltf File To Animate. Go Through [This Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921901/i-want-to-load-entity-to-animate/56946905#56946905)