# I Want To Load Entity To Animate

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js, jsartoolkit

I am using AFrame 0.8.2 . I Want to load an animated model using like FBX Format.

I tried all formats but its  not working . I Imported JSON model with animation ,It Worked But its Hard to get JSON Model. So I want to Load FBX Model  . Here My Cod eIn [GLITCH](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/f489c012-46b2-4da9-8d10-4d8a54433bd7) . Please Edit The Code In Glitch And Provide A Solution .

```
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>

    <a-marker preset='hiro'>

      <a-entity fbx-model=”src: url(https://cdn.glitch.com/c7db968f-5d83-44e4-a392-a5c98687035a%2FNeck_Mech_Walker_by_3DHaupt-(FBX%207.4%20binary%20mit%20Animation).fbx?v=1562244268522);” >
    </a-entity>

    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

When I execute this code and hover HIRO Pattern then i am not able to see any model .

Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using models with glitch.com is a bit tricky, because the `assets` folder is not a single directory.

As you can see, your `.fbx` model has some textures lying around. It means it has some mappings to the texture files.

If you convert the fbx model to a `.gltf` you can change those mappings manually. Just find the:
- texture file paths
- `.bin` path
in the `.gltf` file, and change them into links from the glitch assets.

---

Otherwise you'd need to serve the model locally or upload it to github.

---

This should be in another question but:
- model animations are handled with the [animation-mixer](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders)

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#my-model" animation-mixer="clip: animation-name"></a-entity>
```

- add sound with the [sound component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/sound.html)

```
<a-entity sound="src: url(music.mp3); autoplay: true"></a-entity>
```

---

Glitch with an animated model [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-ar-gltf). Though somethings wrong with the pivot, it definitely loads a model and plays the animation

Comment: glad I could help :)